# Python list bug or am I wrong?

Tags: python, list

I have constructed a 3 level nested list

```
#run on Python 3.2.3  32 bit on Win 7
L2=list(0 for i in range(2))
L3=list(L2 for i in range(3))
L4=list(L3 for i in range(4))
#give a new value to the very first number in list:
L4[0][0][0]=5
print("L4:")
print(L4)
#outputs erronously:
#[[[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]], [[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]], [[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]], [[5, 0], [5, 0], [5, 0]]]
```

The same list given explicitly

```
#the same L4 given explicitly:
anotherL4=[[[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
print("anotherL4:")
#give a new value to the very first number:
anotherL4[0][0][0]=5
print(anotherL4)
#outputs correctly:
#[[[5, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]], [[0, 0], [0, 0], [0, 0]]]
```

Comment: +1 For considering that you might be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

You're wrong. You've copied the reference multiple times, which means they're actually all the same list.

Answer (score 3):

When you write `list(L3 for i in range(4))`, you are telling it to yield the same list L3 on each iteration of the generator comprehension.  When you subsequently modify that list, the modifications show up everywhere, because all of them are references to the same list.

You could get the effect you seem to want by doing

```
list(list(L3) for i in range(4))
```

since using `list(L3)` makes a new list.

Comment: or just `[list(L3) for i in range(4)]`

Answer (score 0):

Just to elaborate,

```
a = 1
b = 2
c = [a,b]
a += 1
print c
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you built a list of *list references* rather than a list of lists.  Since the references all pointed back to a single list, when you mutate that single list, all the references show the change.

```
L0 = range(3)
L1 = range(3)

print(id(L0)) # prints a number
print(id(L1)) # prints a different number
print(id(L0) == id(L1))  # prints False

print(L0 is L1)  # prints False; not same objects
print(L0 == L1)  # prints True; values match

# your original code:
L2=list(0 for i in range(2))
L3=list(L2 for i in range(3))
L4=list(L3 for i in range(4))

print(L3[0] is L2)  # prints True; L3[0] is a reference to L2
```

We can fix it and explicitly show what we are doing by using `copy.deepcopy()`:

```
import copy

L2 = [0 for i in range(2)]
L3 = [copy.deepcopy(L2) for i in range(3)]
L4 = [copy.deepcopy(L3) for i in range(4)]
#give a new value to the very first number in list:
L4[0][0][0]=5
print("L4:")
print(L4)
```

Note that instead of making a generator expression and passing it to `list()` to force it to be expanded out to a list, I just used list comprehensions in the above code to directly make lists.

More usually if you want to do this crazy thing, you should maybe just nest some list comprehensions:

```
L4 = [[[0 for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(3)] for _ in range(4)]
```

This makes it pretty clear that we are building a new list of lists of lists.  And if you use `copy.deepcopy()` you are basically just copying a bunch of zeroes, so you might as well just build new lists using zeroes.

Comment: (as seen in BrenBarn's solution) using `list(L2)` is a better way of cloning a list (especially since this is just a simple list of integers). Importing `deepcopy` for this isn't necessary.

Comment: @shuzOMGchen, my actual suggested solution is the last one.  I think that for educational purposes, the clarity of explicitly calling a Python copy function is worth it.  And you can't build `L4` correctly without `copy.deepcopy()`; you *can* build `L3` using `list(L2)` but if you try to repeat that pattern when you build `L4` you will have some references repeated.  It's simpler to just build the list you want out of zeroes as I showed, but if you really must keep re-copying the nested lists, you need a way to copy a nested list.